# XML error: Markup declaration must be well formed

Tags: xml, markup

[1,3] Message: The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed. How can I fix it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE nta PUBLIC '-//Uppaal Team//DTD Flat System 1.1//EN' 'http://www.it.uu.se/research/group/darts/uppaal/flat-1_1.dtd'><nta><declaration>// Place global declarations here.

chan s0, r0, rack0, sack0;</declaration><template><name x="5" y="5">Sender</name><declaration>// Place local declarations here.
</declaration><location id="id0" x="56" y="80"><name x="64" y="48">WaitAck</name></location><location id="id1" x="-16" y="0"><name x="-32" y="-32">Send</name></location><init ref="id1"/><transition><source ref="id0"/><target ref="id1"/><label kind="synchronisation" x="0" y="64">sack0?</label><nail x="-16" y="80"/></transition><transition><source ref="id1"/><target ref="id0"/><label kind="synchronisation" x="0" y="-16">s0!</label><nail x="56" y="0"/></transition></template><template><name>Medium</name><location id="id2" x="16" y="-24"><name x="6" y="-54">Forward_sack0</name></location><location id="id3" x="16" y="-80"><name x="0" y="-112">Forward_s0</name></location><location id="id4" x="-128" y="-8"><name x="-144" y="-40">Wait</name></location><init ref="id4"/><transition><source ref="id2"/><target ref="id4"/><label kind="synchronisation" x="-56" y="-16">sack0!</label><nail x="16" y="0"/><nail x="-64" y="0"/></transition><transition><source ref="id4"/><target ref="id2"/><label kind="synchronisation" x="-56" y="-40">rack0?</label><nail x="-72" y="-24"/></transition><transition><source ref="id3"/><target ref="id4"/><label kind="synchronisation" x="-56" y="-72">r0!</label><nail x="16" y="-56"/><nail x="-80" y="-56"/></transition><transition><source ref="id4"/><target ref="id3"/><label kind="synchronisation" x="-56" y="-96">s0?</label><nail x="-80" y="-80"/></transition></template><template><name>Receiver</name><location id="id5" x="-88" y="64"><name x="-128" y="64">Ack</name></location><location id="id6" x="-88" y="-24"><name x="-112" y="-56">Receive</name></location><init ref="id6"/><transition><source ref="id5"/><target ref="id6"/><label kind="synchronisation" x="-136" y="8">rack0!</label></transition><transition><source ref="id6"/><target ref="id5"/><label kind="synchronisation" x="-56" y="40">r0?</label><nail x="-16" y="-24"/><nail x="-16" y="64"/></transition></template><system>// Place template instantiations here.

// List one or more processes to be composed into a system.
system Sender, Medium, Receiver;</system></nta>
```

Answer (score 0):

The XML itself that you've posted in your question, while poorly formatted, is well-formed.  The error message refers specifically to the DTD referenced in your XML, but you've not included that in your question.  You should remove the DOCTYPE line, or fix the referenced DTD.  If you have questions on what's wrong with the DTD, you should edit your question and add the DTD to it.

Comment: hi you have three template tags .Reside these in <templates> ........</templates>

Comment: @LDS:  Why?  The error message states *document type declaration must be well-formed*.  Your observation is regarding validity.  [Validity and well-formedness](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134494/290085) are not the same.

Comment: You are currect .But I  open it in google crome and found well and getting taht .But if you validated it may happens

Comment: @LDS: Sorry, but you'll have to write more clearly if you require a response.

Comment: hi Actualy I open it in google crome and it open smothly.If is there any error may not open from top to button

Comment: @LDS: Sorry, I don't feel we're making progress here.  Moving on.  Good luck.